# What order does SQLAlchemy use for primary key columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I create a table like this:

```
table = Table('mytable', metadata,
   Column('a', Integer, primary_key=True),
   Column('b', Integer, primary_key=True),
)
table.create()
```

Is it guaranteed that the primary key will be (a,b) and not (b,a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe echo=True and compare yours with a swapped version?  That should give the answer.

Answer (score 5):

its guaranteed, yes, since `Column` objects in `Table` are ordered.  or if you really want to be explicit, use `PrimaryKeyContraint()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It will be a really bad thing if resulting DDL wasn't giving consistent results.